# .each() jQuery and on click

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to make an image visible if the thumbnail which was clicked on's index matches the index of the hidden image. I am not sure if I am on the right track of not. The first portion of my code, adding a class with 'lght-box' plus it's index is working. The second portion I am having trouble with.

Thanks in advance.

```
    var brigZoom = {
    init : function() {

        var ground = $('.ground-box');
        var lightBox = $('.lght-box img');

        lightBox.each(function(index) {
            $(this).addClass('lght-box' + index);
        });

        ground.hide();
        lightBox.css('visibility', 'hidden');

        var thumbImages = $('.thumbs img');

        thumbImages.each(function(index){
            $this = $(this);
            $this.on('click', function(){
                lightBox[this.index].css('visibility', 'visible');
            });
        });

        }
    };

brigZoom.init();
```

html:

```
    <div class="ground-box"></div>
<div class="lght-box">
    <img src="images/zoom/musings/small/1.jpg" class="images-that-need-zoom" alt="Honor & Beluga" />
    <img src="images/zoom/musings/small/2.jpg" class="images-that-need-zoom" alt="" />
    <img src="images/zoom/musings/small/3.jpg" class="images-that-need-zoom" alt="" />
    <img src="images/zoom/musings/small/4.jpg" class="images-that-need-zoom" alt="" />
    <img src="images/zoom/musings/small/5.jpg" class="images-that-need-zoom" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lightbox` in your code is a jQuery object, by using bracket notation you will have a DOM element object which doesn't have `.css()` method. Also DOM elements don't have `index` property, you are passing `undefined`.

You can use `.index()` method for getting the index and `.eq()` method for selecting an element using an index in another collection.

```
thumbImages.on('click', function(event) {
    // Get the index 
    var i = thumbImages.index(this);
    // Filter an element with the same index in another collection
    lightBox.eq(i).css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: This worked and helped my understanding of the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so It seems to me that you are just following wrong approach.

Here is the quick fix:

```
    lightBox.css('display', 'none');

    var thumbImages = $('.thumbs img');

    thumbImages.click(function(){
        var index = $(this).index();
        lightBox.each(function(i){
            if(i == index)
            {
                $(this).css('display', 'block');
            } 
            else
            {
                $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi try to use bind an not on

```
    thumbImages.each(function(index){
        $this = $(this);
        $this.bind('click', function(){
            lightBox[this.index].css('visibility', 'visible');
        });
    });
```

hope this help you